# test overloaded java methods with spock

Tags: java, groovy, overloading, spock

In my eclipse project I've got a java class that validates if objects of different types are empty using overloaded methods:

```
public class EmptyProof {

    public static boolean isEmpty(String field) {
        System.out.println("String " + field);
        return field == null || field.trim().equals("");
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(BigDecimal d) {
        System.out.println("BI " + d.toString());
        return d == null || d.compareTo(new BigDecimal("0")) == 0;
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(Object input) {
        System.out.println("obj " + input.toString());
        return input == null || String.valueOf(input).length() == 0;
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a Unit Test in Spock:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import spock.lang.Specification;

class EmptyProofSpec extends Specification {

    def 'must evaluate emptiness of a String correctly'() {

        expect: "isEmpty for String returns the right answer"
            System.out.println("test string " + bi.toString());
            EmptyProof.isEmpty(str as String) == result

        where: "using this table"
            str                     || result
            ""                      || true 
            null                    || true
            "a"                     || false
    }

    def 'must evaluate emptiness of a BigInteger correctly'() {

        expect:
            System.out.println("test BigInt " + bi.toString());
            EmptyProof.isEmpty(bi as BigInteger) == result

        where: "using this table"
            bi                                              || result
            BigInteger.ONE                                  || false
            new BigInteger(Integer.MIN_VALUE) as BigInteger || false
//          null as BigInteger                              || true
//          BigInteger.ZERO  as BigInteger                  || true
    }

}
```

This brings me the following output in the console:

```
test string 
String 
test string null
test string a
String a
test BigInt 1
obj 1
test BigInt -2147483648
obj -2147483648
```

As you can see my tests with String objects call isEmpty(String). But my calls with BigInteger do not call isEmpty(BigInteger) but isEmpty(Object). I would like to add my test with BigInteger.ZERO but this would fail as the Object-method does not care about 0's.

I already tried some things like casting and the @CompileStatic annotation. Yet without success.

Can I instruct Spock to use the BigInteger method without a change in my Java class?

Comment: Does `EmptyProof` have to be a Java class? You will not see this problem if it is a Groovy class because of the use of runtime dispatch or multi-methods in Groovy as compared to Java. Appropriate method invocation will be chosen at runtime according to the type of argument, as compared to Java where method is chosen at compile time.

Comment: Groovy also performs multiple dispatch when calling methods in Java classes.

Comment: This comes from a project with more than 100k loc. I do not want to change things before I could introduce a save base of unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it fails over to `isEmpty(Object)` is because there is no method defined for `BigInteger`. The one which is present is defined for `BigDecimal`

```
public static boolean isEmpty(BigDecimal d) { ... }
```

Add/edit one for `BigInteger`.

Also note, `null` case will fall back to `Object`.